# Why some developers prefix variables with the word "my"?

Tags: oop, variables, naming-conventions

I've noticed some of the developers on my team tend to prefix their variables with "my" (i.e. "var myHello = 'Hello World').  These aren't instance variables or anything, just regular variables that reside within a method.

Is there any significance to this naming convention?  To me it comes off a little "newbie-ish" -- as if they just graduated from their LOGO class.  But these are seemingly seasoned devs so I could be way off.

Comment: If you're noticing them as always being local variables, maybe it is possibly a naming convention they've decided on for the team? A bit strange though.

Comment: I don't have a link handy, but I'd be surprised if this hasn't been discussed on Programmers.SE at length.  Personally I agree with your assessment, more often than not it comes off as a lazy name in my opinion.  It's often used in contrived examples, but I can't think of any appropriate uses in production code.

Comment: I think it is generally used to disassociate from inbuilt functionality. For example, if someone decides to make a linked list implementation, they may call it MyLinkedList to make it clear that they are not using java's inbuilt class.

Comment: I've never seen this convention used and I honestly can't think of a "good" reason in general for it. Ask the programmer using this convention what *his/her* rationale is. (In any case, try to write questions free from subjective bias or presenting opinions.)

Answer (score 1):

I totally disagree with you. leaving the fact that judging a person's skill by variable names imply that he's newbie aside, some teams have code standards other than you're used to. For your information - in PERL if you didn't know there's a reserved word `my variable` and it has nothing to do with coding standards. Maybe he had no better name for that class which is already implemented in the system but he wants to keep things simple? Besides, maybe he likes to reference himself to the code he writes?

Comment: In Perl `my` roughly replaces `var`, so such logic seems like a bit of a stretch..